# matplotlib 'int' object not callable with basic plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just starting to learn how to use mpl, and I'm getting a weird 'int not callable' error.

`x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.xlim = -1, 11
plt.ylim = -1.5, 1.5`

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Anybody know why this could be? It's totally perplexing to me. Here's an image of the error.

[image]

EDIT: x was defined as above in a different cell, to clarify.

Comment: In a brand new notebook, I have been able to run the code perfectly.

Comment: By the way, your screenshot is different from what you typed out.

Comment: You haven't by any chance happend to write`plt.xlim = ...` (where `...` means any number or variable) in a cell somewhere prior to this?

Comment: You have redefined `plt.xlim` using `plt.xlim = -1, 11` (same with ylim). Delete those lines, restart the kernel and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax.set_xlim(-1, 11);
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5);
```

[image]